# Vuejs Large file Upload crashes Browser

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js, input

My file upload crashes my browser(chrome), files with the size of 30mb work fine, but if I try to upload a file which has a size of 150mb the browser crashes.

The max upload size of the server is already configured properly, it as a browser error / crash no server side error message.

This is the logic to accomplish the upload:

```
<input
    type="file"
    ref="src"
    accept="*"
    @change="onFilePicked"
>

onFilePicked (e) {
    const files = e.target.files;
    if(files[0] !== undefined) {
        this.upload.src.name = files[0].name;
        this.upload.src.type = files[0].name;
        this.file.object = files[0];
        if (this.upload.src.name.lastIndexOf('.') <= 0) return;
        const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
        fr.addEventListener('load', () => {
            this.upload.src.url = fr.result;
            this.upload.src.file = files[0]; 
        });
        fr.onload = () => {
            this.uploadSource();
        }
    } else {
        this.upload.src.name = '';
        this.upload.src.file = '';
        this.upload.src.url = '';
    }
},
```

Comment: I had same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers. The issue is that browsers have limits when uploading large files. Depending on your browser the limit may vary.

You'll have to split the file into chunks and upload the checks to the server.